# update database on browser exit

Tags: php, html, css

does anybody know how to update a mysql database if a user exits a browser or navigates away from a page? I have a value set to 1 and want it setting to 0 in such an event. I have been banging my head against the wall with this for weeks and any help would be massively appreciated, thanks. I'm using PHP. I have tried it on body unload but it does not do what I want.

Comment: `I have a value set to 1 and want it setting to 0 in such an event.` -- are you using this value to check for Online/Offline users?

Comment: Why is `onUnload` not working for you? That sounds like exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: @eykanal: most browsers doesn't allow sending ajax requests during (before)unload and in some (poor) browsers you've a race condition: does the async ajax request get sent before the window closes? You definitely don't want to send an ajax request during (before)unload.

Answer (score 4):

Don't do that. Simply because you rely on the browser to send you a notification (through the `beforeunload` event) or some other mechanism. What will happen if the browser crashes, or the user put his computer to sleep/hibernate?

You may consider other options, something like a PING! method that the browser could send through Ajax calls every 1 min or so telling he's still alive. All you'd need to do is to create a MySQL procedure that would scan for any "alive" entry more than 1:30 min old (call that `last_seen TIMESTAMP` or something) and set it your "alive" to 0. This procedure could be called at random requests (pretty much like the PHP session cleanup mechanism).

This will ensure that the user is still there since you will get PING! requests periodically and when the user stops, you will be able to safely say that he won't PING! anymore (though it will cause a light delay, but an acceptable one). This will also ensure user security.

Answer (score 0):

PHP can only change things when a page is ACCESSED. From the PHP perspective, as soon as the script ends, the transaction is over and it have nothing to do with that page anymore.

The only way to do this is keeping the connection open, the script running, and use something like this:

```
<?php

  function shutdown()
  {
     // here you change the value on your db...
  }

  register_shutdown_function('shutdown');

 // send the data to client
  echo "anything";
  flush();
  // sleep for a lot of time... 99999 seconds...
  sleep(99999);
?>
```

Comment: some web hostings will "kill" the PHP process after a few seconds (like 25 on 1and1) so this is unpractical. Plus, it may be fine for a few users, but this also opens flood attacks...